# unable to use android licesing library

Tags: android, android-lvl

I'm having a real bad time trying to get Licensing to work.  I'm following the docs at [this location](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html).  I built the LVL library from the existing code in the Google Play Licensing Library and put the library into my workspace along with my android project.

I'm using code from [this example](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/android-app-developers/69899-market-license-easy-implementation-protect-your-apps.html) that packages the licensing logic into a separate activity but I believe this is moot to the problem I'm having as I have tried it from my own main activity too.

THE PROBLEM IS: I cannot import com.android.vending.licensing...

The graphic below illustrates the problem.  Internet research on this issue turns up many developers having this and related problems but none of the solutions work for me.

Does anyone have a clue?

[image: My Project in Eclipse]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on LVLibrary -> Properties -> Android
Check if isLibrary is selected (checked)
THen go into your com.deanblake... and right click on that, then same as above but where you see reference check if the libarary is added (doesnt have an x next to  it). If not just click Add and select LVLibrary.

Comment: is library is indeed checked in the LVLLibray project and in my apps project LVLLibrary is indeed added (and is library in not checked).

Comment: Also check if the import is proper. because I have noticed that the screen says com.android.vending which is weird because I have com.google.android

Comment: it is com.google.android.vending.licensing (more bad google docs costing us sooooo much time) but that does not work either.  I notice there is no source in the library src directory.  I wonder if that is right.

Comment: no thats wrong. you have to have the full src in the library directory. my latest library file has this src path src\com\google\android\vending\licensing

and all those files (AESObfuscator, LicenseChecker etc)

Comment: I was going about importing the library the wrong way.  It was a combination of Pilot error and bad google docs.  Imports now work.  Thanks.